# Approach to database utility scripts in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

My AWS Amplify app requires some "seed" data that needs to start in the database. The mechanism by which this runs should not be accessible to users of the app. What is the most idiomatic way to load data into DynamoDB for this purpose?

I have looked into creating a lambda function for this purpose (ie `amplify function add`), which is well integrated into amplify. However *there is no easy way to actually invoke this lambda*. Amplify doesn't tell you the lambda ID for use with the `aws` command, and there is no `amplify` command that relates to *invoking* a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of alternative ways to do that. One could be using CDK, CloudFormation, Terraform or other IaC tool to create initial DynamoDB tables and items.